# jQuery add a class to an element if there is another element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide a div container when there is no `<h5>` in it. Normally the div container would be hide. When the server pulls feeds from other website, a `<h5>` will be add inside the div container. Then the div should show up on the page.

Here is a simplify version of the HTML structure without out `<h5>`

```
<div id="alert-feed">
    <div class="webpart-title">Title</div>
    <div class="webpart-body">
        <div class="contianer">
            <ul class="feedlist">
                <li class="campusfeed">
                    <ul class="articlelist"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML with `<h5>`

```
<div id="alert-feed">
    <div class="webpart-title">Title</div>
    <div class="webpart-body">
        <div class="contianer">
            <ul class="feedlist">
                <li class="campusfeed">
                    <ul class="articlelist">
                        <li>
                            <a><h5 class="articletitle"></h5></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to hide the `#alert-feed` by adding a class `no-alert` when there is no `<h5>` inside it. I know this could be simply done by using `hasClass` and `addClass`, but the structure is really confusing me and I can't do anything about it. So could someone help me to figure out how to do this?

Comment: How do you add `h5` tag?

Answer (score 5):

Try this - needs to be run after you have tried to pull your feeds from another website

```js
var feed = $('#alert-feed');   // get your feed
if (!feed.find('h5').length) { // check if it doesn't contain a h5
  feed.addClass('no-alert');   // if it doesn't, add a class
}
```

Comment: OP wants to add class when there is no `h5` inside `#alert-feed`. I think your current variant doing opposite. It should be `if (!feed.find('h5').length) { ... }`

Comment: I just realised that and was editing as you typed your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just wants to hide `#alert-feed` based on presence or absence of `h5` inside it, you can try this code:

```
if(!$('#alert-feed h5').length) {
    $('#alert-feed').hide();
}
```

Otherwise if class is needed then:

```
if(!$('#alert-feed h5').length) {
    $('#alert-feed').addClass('no-alert');
}
```

Comment: this will only find the direct h5 child of the element with id `alert-feed`?

Comment: @EdwardBlack No, it can find `h5` to any level inside `#alert-feed`. For direct `h5` we need to write it as `$('#alert-feed > h5')`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `not()` function > [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

see code snippet below. let me know if it helps

```js
$( ".articlelist" ).not( ":has(h5)" ).addClass( "no-alert" );
```

```css
.no-alert li { color:red;}
.articlelist:not(.no-alert) { color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-feed">
    <div class="webpart-title">Title</div>
    <div class="webpart-body">
        <div class="contianer">
            <ul class="feedlist">
                <li class="campusfeed">
                    <ul class="articlelist">
                      <li>
                        <a><h5 class="articletitle">h5 is here !</h5></a>
                      </li>
                      
                    </ul>
                     <ul class="articlelist">
                      <li>
                        no h5 here ! 
                      </li>
                      
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We dont see whats even happening. Add a start button which triggers your code, so we can see the difference.

Comment: edited the answer so as it's more clear. but it was as easy as inspecting the element and you would've seen if the code provided by me worked or not